# Serialize list of objects with json_serializable without creating extra class

Tags: serialization, flutter, dart

I saw [a tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47) where an extra class is created just to be able to serialize a list of objects, instead of a single object:

I'm using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to generate some serialization code for my class `Preference`, but now I want to save a list of preferences using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and I get an error obviously.

```
var sSavedPrefs = json.encode(PreferenceRepo.getSavedPrefs());
prefs.setString(saved_prefs_key, sSavedPrefs );
```

I used

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Preference{...}
```

to make it serializable, but I don't want to create an extra class like

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Preferences{...}
```

just to make it work - is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:
Using the `setStringList` method I could create a `List` where I added each serialized object one by one without needing an extra list class. I also noticed that `json.encode` might not have been the right method to use, I saw `jsonEncode` in [another tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) and used it instead:

```
List<String> savedPrefsJson = [];
for (Preference savedPref in PreferenceRepo.savedPrefs) {
  String savedPrefJson = jsonEncode(savedPref);
  savedPrefsJson.add(savedPrefJson);
}
prefs.setStringList(saved_prefs_key, savedPrefsJson);
```